# Excel: Taking standard deviation of a subset of data

Tags: excel-formula

[image]

I am working with a pivot table and am trying to take the standard deviation of two types of data "001" and "002" which are interspersed between years. I feel like I'm looking for a STDEV.P(IF....) function but I am not having much luck

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you give an example of the data and expected output?

Comment: I believe that I should be using a DSTDEV function but it isnt cooperation. Below is the example                                                                                                                             002 26-Mar-19 12800
002 28-Mar-19 12800
001 01-Mar-18 19300
001 02-Mar-18 34000
001 07-Feb-18 33300
001 14-Mar-18 18000
002 06-Aug-20 13000

Comment: You will want to change the design to show tabular form and repeat all item labels.  Then you can use something like: `STDEV.P(IF(C:C="001",D:D))`

Comment: Thank you I will try tha t